# Clearing Dead Letter Queue

Tags: msmq

What are the different ways of clearing a dead letter queue?

Suppose that a dead letter queue gets piled up with so many messages, is there any way that can be cleared manually.

Comment: To clear manually, you just right click the queue, All Tasks->Purge?

Comment: As that has worked for you, I've put it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clear manually, you need to right click the queue, then select All Tasks->Purge.